# SQL Server full text search max performance limits within time window

Tags: sql-server, elasticsearch, full-text-search

Let's say we have a table with 100 million records. Which are transactions of sales form multiple sellers. Each record has around 14 columns

TABLE **SellerTransactions**

```
 string SellerId,
 string ProductId,
 DateTime CreateDate,
 string BankNumber,
 string Name(name+' '+surname+' 'alias),
 string Comments,
 decimal Amount
 etc...
```

Each year we will add around 60 million new records.. and the record count will increase by 10% yearly +-

Search will be done by seller Id, then by product Id or products Id's(for multiple products in a time period for that seller).

Now every search will be filtered by time usually 1 week period/ mostly the last week but its also possible to have worst case scenarios when we will search within all the data we have: years.

And also a search should be possible by bank number, or full text search by name or part of it.

```
SELECT * 
FROM SellerTransactions
WHERE SelledId = 'Seller1Guid' 
  AND ProductId IN 'ProductGuid1,ProductGuid2..' 
  AND (CreateDate <= CurrentDate AND CreateDate >= (CurrendDate - 7 days)) 
  AND CONTAINS(Name, "BoB Skynet")
ORDER BY CreateDateTime 
TAKE 20 SKIP 20
```

So search time consumption in regards to these scenarios:

- After filtering by id's & time range search in up to 10k records
- After filtering by id's & time range search in up to 100k records
- After filtering by id's & time range search in up to 1 million records
- After filtering by id's & time range search in up to 1 to 10 million records

in these cases would it be 0.5s? or 1s or up to 20s?

Also how would the search performance would change if we would also add search in comments column as well as name?

```
CONTAINS(Name, "BoB Skynet") OR CONTAINS(Comments, "online")
```

In most cases the searching should be done on small records counts, in very rare cases we would go though millions of rows.. but how much time would it take?

When it would be an good idea to move to Elastic search for example?
Well we are storing a bit of data, but request count for this data is usually small.

Comment: Unfortunately, the only answer to questions like this are "try it and see" - there are too many variables.  What hardware are you running on?  Physical machine or virtual server?  How many users?  etc., etc.

Comment: @Brian sql server in a server.. user count is relatively small on peak times guessing max 200 request/s probably less... I suppose a physical machine? I mean its corporate hardware.

Comment: Sorry, @Greeed - I wasn't asking for that information.  I was listing some of the "too many variables".  My initial response - the only answer to questions like this are "try it and see" - still stands.  And I know - that doesn't help you when you have managers asking for answers without testing.